# Returning a pointer to a 2-D array from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

In order to understand how pointer work I wrote this function which has to return a 3*3 matrix.

```
int** Matrix::getMatrix(){
    cout<<"The  matrix is: \n";
    int (*p)[3]=m;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        cout<<m[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return p;

}
```

Here `m` is a 3*3 array.But at the line `return p;` it gives the error `return value type does not match function type`.

With p am I not returning a pointer to a 3*3 matrix.?What's wrong with this.Can someone please help me to correct this.

Comment: I believe, you should be returning a type `int*`, which would return the value of p (ie., address of m) instead of `int**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int (*)[3]` and `int**` are not the same type:

- `int**` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`
- `int (*)[3]` is a pointer of an array of 3 `int`.

Even if `int [3]` may decay to `int*`, pointer on there different type are also different.

The correct syntax to return `int (*)[3]` would be:

```
int (*Matrix::getMatrix())[3];
```

or with `typedef`:

```
using int3 = int[3];

int3* Matrix::getMatrix();
```

And as `m` is `int[3][3]`, you may even return reference (`int(&)[3][3]`):

```
int (&Matrix::getMatrix())[3][3];
```

and with typedef:

```
using mat3 = int[3][3];
mat3& Matrix::getMatrix();
```

It would be more intuitive with `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: In the first line you are missing an asterix in `int**`.

Comment: `auto Matrix::getMatrix() -> decltype(m)` (plus something to make it a reference)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `decltype(m)&` is the way. Even in C++14 with `auto` ( `int(*)[3]`) or `decltype(auto)` (`int[3][3]` that you can't return) doesn't improve that.

Comment: @Jarod42 What is the difference of `int (*)[3]` and `int**`.I don't know much about pointers.Still beginning to learn it. Also what is meant by `int (*Matrix::getMatrix())[3];
`.What does `*Matrix` mean?Pointer to a class?

Comment: @clarkson: I edited the answer for clarification of the difference.

Comment: @clarkson: `int(*f())[3]` is the (unintuitive) syntax to return pointer on array of 3 int. I would recommend to not use it. Prefer the syntax with `typedef` or appropriate structure (generic `std::array<T, N>` or a dedicated class of your own).